# ffmpeg avcodec_decode_video2 function error codes

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

i use at the function `avcodec_decode_video2` at the flowing way:

```
if (packet.isEOF()) {
    AVPacket eofpkt;
    av_init_packet(&eofpkt);
    eofpkt.data = NULL;
    eofpkt.size = 0;
    ret = avcodec_decode_video2(d.codec_ctx, d.frame, &got_frame_ptr, &eofpkt);
} else {
    ret = avcodec_decode_video2(d.codec_ctx, d.frame, &got_frame_ptr, (AVPacket*)packet.asAVPacket());
}
//qDebug("pic_type=%c", av_get_picture_type_char(d.frame->pict_type));
d.undecoded_size = qMin(packet.data.size() - ret, packet.data.size());
if (ret < 0) {
    //qWarning("[VideoDecoderFFmpegBase] %s", av_err2str(ret));
    return false;
}
if (!got_frame_ptr) {
    qWarning("no frame could be decompressed: %s %d/%d", av_err2str(ret), d.undecoded_size, packet.data.size());
    return !packet.isEOF();
}
```

When i run it I get an error (I go inside  `if(!got_frame_ptr)` ) and in the printing i get that ret value's is:
203,3053,5120
(or more accurate tis is my printings:

`Warning: "no frame could be decompressed: Error number 203 occurred 0/203"
Warning: "no frame could be decompressed: Error number 3053 occurred 0/3053"
Warning: "no frame could be decompressed: Error number 5120 occurred 0/5120"`

(`av_err2str(ret)` just print decorated ret, nothing more))

the `avcodec_decode_video2` docomentatin said:
`On error a negative value is returned, otherwise the number of bytes used or zero if no frame could be decompressed.`

i'm not in situation that avcodec_decode_video2 return me negative value, but i do get zero at got_frame_ptr , instead of got_frame_ptr will be the same value as `ret` like doc. said i get this odd value (203,3053,5120).

my questions is:

1. what this error code means? (i search at ffmpeg doc. and i didn't found a good record on what every numeric value should represent)
2. why i get this values from this function? is it ffmpeg bug? or did i didn't understand ffmpeg currectly?

thank you
g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an error to not finish decompressing a frame, frame decoding tends to be delayed by a few frames to enable frame multi-threading.

[edit]
In other words, if `ret >= 0 && got_frame_ptr == 0`, just continue as normal and assume it was successful but output was delayed. The delayed data will come back at the end when flushing the queue with `NULL` packets.